# Can not establish connection with jdbc:iotdb://127.0.0.1:6667/

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I upgraded IoTDB to v1.2.2 yesterday on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine. Now the "sbin/start-standalone.sh" script works fine, but the "sbin/start-cli.sh -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6667 -u root -pw root" script refuses to connect with "Error: Can not establish connection with jdbc:iotdb://127.0.0.1:6667/ : Socket is closed by peer.. Host is 127.0.0.1, port is 6667."

I was expecting the CLI to login with an interactive shell. Am running openjdk v11.0.20.1 with _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx10240m. Have opened port 6667 with ufw for both tcp & tcpv6 [ALLOW Anywhere]. "netstat -tulpn | grep 6667" produces "tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:6667 :::* LISTEN 5761/java". Rebooting did not help. Immediately preceding the error message is: "SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]"

Answer (score 0):

Port 6667 is the one used by Internet Relay Chat (IRC), and I had just tested a chat program. What does chat use? UDP. So the following output made sense:
sudo iptables -L | grep 6667
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:6667
ACCEPT     udp  --  localhost/24         anywhere             udp dpt:6667

This implies I had to change the IPTABLES on my machine using:
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 127.0.0.1 --dport 6667 -j ACCEPT

This is the way to make this change persistent:
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent  # allow the program to save the current set of rules to /etc/iptables/rules.v4

This site gave me the clues to resolve this issue: https://upcloud.com/resources/tutorials/configure-iptables-ubuntu